# regularity of finite flat branched covers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, branched-covers

Let $D$ and $S$ be two regular schemes and let $D$ be a divisor of $S$. Let $C \to S$ be a finite flat morphism, branched along $D$. Is $C$ regular as well?

Comment: I am not sure what branched means. But if $D$ is an affine line over $\spec \mathbb C$, $S$ a closed point of $D$ (so $D$ and $S$ are
clearly regular), and $C$ the union of two copies of $D$, intersecting at the point $S$, then the natural morphism $C \rightarrow D$ (the one sending each irreducible components of $D$
to $C$ by the identity map) is finite flat, and étale outside $S$,
while $C$ is not regular. 

Comment: Joel: right. Anyway, in your example the *schematic* branch locus is not reduced (is one point counted with multiplicity two). Indeed, your cover is the limit of a family of flat double covers $f_t \colon \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1$, all branched in two points, when the two points come together.

Comment: Ah okay. So what is the definition of the schematic branch locus?



Comment: @Francesco: We should be able to see that the schematic branch locus has multiplicity two by looking at the ring map $\mathbb{C}[x]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2-y^2)$. So Joël's question is pertinent: what is the definition of branch locus? If this is not a counterexample for the OP's definition of branched along $D$ (because it is actually branched along $2D$, which is not regular) then maybe your deleted (why?) answer was the right one.

Comment: Ok, so let use the following definition that can be found in the paper by Iversen "Numerical invariants of multiple planes", p. 971. Let $x \in S$ and $y_1, \ldots, y_r$ be the points of $f^{-1}x$. Let $d_i$ be the discriminant of the extension $\widehat{\mathcal{O}_x} \to \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{y_i}}$. Then a local equation of $D$ in $x$ is given by $\prod d_i$.  

Comment: Alternatively, one can use Hurwitz formula to define the branch locus, at least when $C$ is Gorenstein. 
In fact, $K_C = f^*K_S + R$, where $R$ is the ramification divisor. Then $D=f_*R$ as a cycle, so it makes sense to speak of non-reduced branch divisor.
For instance, in Joel example the ramification divisor is the intersection of the two lines. It is linearly equivalent to a general fibre of the covering, which is given by two distinct points sent by $f$ to the same point. So $f_*R=D$ is a point counted with multiplicity *two*. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **yes** when $\dim D=2$ and the variety upstairs (i.e. $C$ in your notation) is *normal*: 
see

Bas Edixhoven, Robin de Jong, Jan Schepers, [*Covers of surfaces with fixed branch locus*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.0184v2.pdf), Lemma 2.1.

It seems plausible that this proof can be extended in any dimension $\geq 3$, although I did not check it carefully.

Comment: My comments don't make sense any more, so I'll delete them in a moment.